# Enum Localization generic approach

Tags: java, spring-mvc, enums, internationalization

**Enum**

```
public enum EmployeeStatus {
        ACTIVE, IN_ACTIVE
}
```

In  callers scattered all over the application whicg get and set the enum like below. Here are examples

**Caller_1**

```
if(employee.getStatus() == EmployeeStatus.STATUS.SUBMITTED) {
```

}

**Caller_2**

```
employee.setStatus(EmployeeStatus.STATUS.SUBMITTED)
```

**Problem**

I need to implement the internationalization so that end user sees the employee status as per locale. So when i set the status for french locale
it should set the  value from right resource bundel.  Is there a way i can achieve this without changing the caller code. Here is the solution
I can think of

**My proposed solution :-**

```
public enum EmployeeStatus {
        ACTIVE, IN_ACTIVE

    public static String toString() {
        return I18n.getMessage("label." + this);
    }
}


public final class I18n {
    private I18n() {
    }


    private static ResourceBundle bundle;

    public static String getMessage(String key) {

        if(bundle == null) {
            bundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle("path.to.i18n.messages");
        }
        return bundle.getString(LocaleContextHolder.getLocale());

    }


}
```

With this approach I need to add `toString` method in every Enum without change in caller ?  Is there a better generic approach spring provides ?

I am using spring 4. See if spring can help here .

Comment: What are you using for end user interface ?

Comment: Instead of overriding `toString`, which may cause issues if the `enum` elements are interpreted from or to `String` anywhere in your source, why don't you simply add a `toLocalizedString` method to your enum (pretty much with the same logic as your current override, and change not the clients themselves, but the localized views displaying the value?

Comment: You could write an annotation processor to generate the toString method, but that's not spring specific.

Comment: @Mena If I add  `toLocalizedString ` in that case  i need to change my views(which may be large in number) as you said.  Regarding your point `Instead of overriding toString, which may cause issues if the enum elements are interpreted from or to String anywhere in your source`  . My point is enum value will  be compared against enum only. For example in  `employee.getStatus() == EmployeeStatus.STATUS.SUBMITTED` on both side status per locale(will be fetched from request) will be compared . Is n't it ? Am i missing any point ?

Comment: @user3198603 in theory, no, you're not missing any point. However, if there's any serialization of your users or enums at any point (which wouldn't necessarily require any explicit invocation to `toString` from your side), this might get tricky, as you'd get the localized string instead of the enum name. Thinking of Jackson here for instance, as it's used by Spring. So my concern is more about the general purpose of `toString` and some pitfalls you may bump into at a later stage.